# Node class instance is not callable

Tags: python, algorithm, testing

I'm trying to run many tests in a code that I made for test the concept of linked lists. In the first test, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LinkedList_test.py", line 14, in test_insert_first_node_to_head
    self.assertEqual('head', self.linked_list.head().value)
TypeError: 'Node' object is not callable
```

The LinkedList code:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        self.previous = None

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def append_node_to_head(self, new_element):
        current = new_element
        current.next = self.head
        self.head = current
               
    def head(self):
        return self.head

   ...other methods
```

The test code:

```
import unittest
from LinkedList import LinkedList, Node

class TestLinkedList(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.linked_list = LinkedList()

    def test_insert_first_node_to_head(self):
        self.linked_list.append_node_to_head(Node('head'))
        self.assertEqual('head', self.linked_list.head().value)

   ...other tests
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like `head` is a plain data attribute, not a function.  Why are you trying to call it `head()` as though it were a function?

Comment: Your code has no definition of a `test_insert_first_node_to_head()` method that's shown in the traceback.

Comment: Add the function mentioned in the error traceback to your question

Comment: I was confused because Stackoverflow requires more text than code in the question and ended up putting the wrong snippets, I will correct it now.

Comment: @JohnGordon You're right. I changed the name of the head function to headF and the error disappeared. I had an attribute called head in LinkedList and a function also called head, the test was calling the attribute.

Comment: @trincot I'm already fixing this .... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined a property `head` and a method `head`. When you then execute:

```
self.linked_list.head()
```

... you are not referencing the `head` method, but the `head` property. That property is not a function, but an instance of `Node`. Hence the error message:

> TypeError: 'Node' object is not callable

The simple solution is to just forget about the method (remove it), and to write;

```
self.linked_list.head
```

...without the parentheses.

If however, you want to have the method, then rename the property:

```
class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self._head = head  # renamed

    def append_node_to_head(self, current):
        current.next = self._head  # renamed
        self._head = current  # renamed
               
    def head(self):
        return self._head  # renamed
```